# Memory management of SWIG generated objects passed to C

Tags: python, c++, memory-management, swig

I am trying to wrap a library for Python written in C++ using SWIG. The library uses function calls that accept byte buffers as parameters. In Python I am creating these byte buffers using %array_class from SWIG . I made a proof-of-concept program in order to test this out and I noticed a significant memory leak associated with passing these buffers to C++. Specifically, running the code below **steadily raises the memory usage of the Python application** (as observed on the Task Manager) up to about 250MB where the program halts. The printouts from C indicate that the program **does run** as expected, but just eats up more memory. The `del buff` statement runs, but does nothing to release the memory. I tried creating and deleting the buffer in each loop, but same result.
Running `delete x;` in C++ crashes my program entirely.

My Swig Interface file:

```
%module example
%include "carrays.i"
%array_class(uint8_t, buffer);
%{
    #include "PythonConnector.h"
%}
%include "PythonConnector.h"
```

The C header file:

```
class PythonConnector {
    public:
        void print_array(uint8_t *x);
};
```

The minimal C-defined function

```
void PythonConnector::print_array(uint8_t *x) 
{
   //int i;
   //for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
   //   printf("[%d] = %d\n", i, x[i]);
   //}
   //delete x;     // <-- This crashed the program
   return;
}
```

The tester Python script

```
import time
import example

sizeBytes = 10000
buff = example.buffer(sizeBytes) 
for j in range(1000):
    # Initialize data buffer
    for i in range(sizeBytes):
        buff[i] = i%256
    buff[0] = 0
    example.PythonConnector().print_array(buff.cast())
    print(j)
del buff
time.sleep(10)
```

Am I missing something? I suspect that SWIG creates some proxy object for each time the buffer is passed to the C++ that is not garbage-collected.

Edit:

- SWIG version 3.0.7
- CPython version 3.5 x64
- Windows 10 OS

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I reckon the leak comes from the repeated calls to  `example.PythonConnector()` if I had to guess. You've posed the question really well - almost everything needed to try it out is there. Can you add the class definition to your example though as well? I imagine it's just `class PythonConnector { public: void print_array(unit8_t*); };` but it would be good to check before I (or others) investigate this further. (Also which version of SWIG and Python are you using?)

Comment: @Flexo I made the additions you suggested. I also moved the instantiation of the python connector outside the loop (instantiate only once) and worked like a charm. Memory stays at 6MB constantly. Thanks.

Comment: Hopefully I'll write up an answer explaining why that happens later this weekend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, Thanks to @Flexo, I found the answer.

The problem is the instantiation of the example.PythonConnector() being created in each loop. Instantiating only once outside the loop seems to fix the memory problem:

```
import time
import example

sizeBytes = 10000
buff = example.buffer(sizeBytes) 
conn = example.PythonConnector()
for j in range(1000):
    # Initialize data buffer
    for i in range(sizeBytes):
        buff[i] = i%256
    buff[0] = 0
    conn.print_array(buff.cast())
    print(j)
del buff
time.sleep(10)
```

There still remains the question why the many connectors don't get garbage collected in the original code.